# WPF: How to bind two TextBoxes across two different user controls

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

I have two sibling user controls having one TextBoxes each. I need to create a two way binding between these two TextBoxes.

The content posted [here](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2007/12/databinding-in-usercontrol.html) is close to my requirement but it describes binding in two controls one in a user control and other in user control's parent. In my case, both the binding controls are in two different user controls, which have a common parent.

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: Are you binding something from Model to those TextBoxes?

Comment: You could bind them both to the same property belonging to the mutual parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ElementName` binding:

```
Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=SecondTextBox, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: I need to know how to use ElementName when you need to bind text box in user control A from text box in user control B; while A and B have a common parent.

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal Ok. Do you use `MVVM`?

Comment: @ArpitKhandelwal And what's problem do you get using the code sample above?